# login form instantly refreshes page when info is entered incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to make a registration and login page, so far everything works except for one thing, when i try to log in, if i use the full email address the page instantly refreshes the page, but if i input an email wrong for example "test", it will tell me it is wrong. but if i try and input a proper email "test@test.com" it will just refresh the page if i enter the wrong password. so far i have this coded.

```
<div id="mainsection">
    <div id="loginPara">
    <form id="usrDetails" onsubmit = "return false()">
        Enter Email address:<br>  
        <input type="email" id="emailInput" required><br>
        Enter Password:<br>
        <input type="password" id="passwordInput" require><br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="login()">
    </form>
    </div>

<p id="loginFailure" style="color:red"></p>
</div>
<script>
    function checkLogin(){
        if(localStorage.loggedInUsrEmail !== undefined){
            //extract details of logged in user
            var usrObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[localStorage.loggedInUsrEmail]);
            //say hello to logged in user
            document.getElementById("loginPara").innerHTML = usrObj.firstName + " logged in.";
        }
    }

    function login(){
        //get email address
        var email = document.getElementById("emailInput").value;

        //user does not have an account
        if(localStorage[email] === undefined){
            //inform user that they do not have an account
            document.getElementById("loginFailure").innerHTML = "email not recognized. do you have an account?";
            return false; //do nothing else
        }
        else {//user has an account
            var usbObj = JSON.parse(localStorage[email]);//convert to object
            var password = document.getElementById("passwordInput").value;
            if(password === usbObj.password){//successful login
            document.getElementById("loginPara").innerHTML= usbObj.firstName + " logged in."
            document.getElementById("loginFailure").innerHTML = "";
            localStorage.loggedInUsrEmail = usbObj.email;
            }
            else{document.getElementById("loginFailure").innerHTML = "Password not correct, please try again.";
             }   
        }
    }
```

can anyone please help me?

Comment: Where's PHP here?

Comment: the PHP is on a separate file but with the coding posted i didnt use php for it.

Comment: Are you sure sending the password using JSON to the browser is a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is invalid

```
<form id="usrDetails" onsubmit = "return false()">
```

You need to return false without the parenthesis().

Comment: thanks, i put that there by mistake but even before when that wasnt there it wasnt working, but now it works